# How to add video html5 "controls" on click ? (jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-video

I'm trying to code my own website, fully handmade but i have a small issue. I would like to add on my website few html5 videos with the basic player.

To hide the controls, and make something clean, I added a quick js script so : when the user clicks on the thumbnail (the poster of the video), the video starts. However, I would've liked to add to that, when the user clicks, it also add the controls attributes of the video in question to be able to use the fullscreen or advance in the video.

**So, here is my script for now :**

```
        jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
            $('.myHTMLvideo').click(function() {
                this.paused ? this.play() : this.pause();
            });
        });
```

And then, I would like that when "onclick", we add the attribute controls in my  to be able to play with the video, and when I click again, it can potentially disappear.

I had already tried a previous script, but when I clicked on a video, it displayed the controls on all my videos on the same page...

Below my html video div :

```
<div class="tile video">
 <video preload="auto" class="myHTMLvideo" poster="#">
 <source src="#" type="video/mp4">
 </video> 
</div>
```

Let me know what is the best option for you guys ...
And thanks for you help, of course !

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.myHTMLvideo').click(function() {
  if (this.paused) {
    this.play();
  $(this).attr('controls', true); // this will add controls attribute
   } else {
     this.pause();
    $(this).removeAttr('controls'); // and this will remove controls attribute
   }
  });
});
```

To play the video on click with the controls appear

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.myHTMLvideo').click(function() {
    var video = $(this).find('video')[0];
    if (video && video.paused) {
       video.setAttribute('controls', '');
       video.play();
    } else if (video) {
          video.pause();
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your quick reply !! Is it possible to play the video on click with the controls appear ? Right now, if I click on the video, I can see the controls appears but I have to click a play button again to start the video.

Comment: Yes, by adding the controls attribute to the video element and then triggering the play() method.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand well to be honest ...

Comment: I saw your edited answer but it's not working :/

Comment: what's the issue  showing up in the modified one?

Comment: It says "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'paused')"

Comment: while accessing pause it  looks like the video element is not being found.  I'll  rewrite the code

Comment: Thanks Suhel, let me know when you have times ! :)) (because for now it's not working, no error message but nothing happen when i click)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

small modification in your script

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          $('.myHTMLvideo').click(function() {
            if (this.paused) {
            
              $(this).attr('controls', ''); 
               this.play();
            } else {
            
              $(this).removeAttr('controls'); 
              this.pause();
            }
          });
        });
```

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          $('.myHTMLvideo').click(function() {
            if (this.paused) {
            
              $(this).attr('controls', ''); 
               this.play();
            } else {
            
              $(this).removeAttr('controls'); 
              this.pause();
            }
          });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="tile video">
 <video preload="auto" class="myHTMLvideo" style="width:300px;" poster="#">
 <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video> 
</div>
<div class="tile video">
 <video preload="auto" class="myHTMLvideo" style="width:300px;" poster="#">
 <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time! Is it possible to play the video on click with the controls appear ? Right now, if I click on the video, I can see the controls appears but I have to click a play button again to start the video.

Comment: small modification add controls first then play the video like $(this).attr('controls', '');  this.play();

Comment: I'm not sure I understand well .. I mean, I understand on the principe but I can't write it for now ... :/

Comment: Can you edit your question by adding html video element tags for better answer

Comment: Done ! Let me know your thoughts!

Comment: Thanks but still not working on my end.

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer of @Suhel Khan, here is my script for now :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myHTMLvideo').click(function() {
    var video = $(this).find('video')[0]
    console.log(video);
    if (video.paused) {
      video.setAttribute('controls', '');
      video.play();
    } else {
      video.pause();
    }
  });
});
```

But I have an error now : *"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'paused')"* and as you can see, the variable **video** is **undefined**.

I feel that I'm close to solving my problem, but the variable video doesn't seem to give the necessary information to have the **controls** appear and and start **playing** the video at the same time.

Comment: Replace `console.log(video);` with `alert("video is: " + video);` and let me know what it says (select pop-up text then copy/paste here).